# How do I access a file launching an Firemonkey iOS app?

Tags: ios, firemonkey

I'm using Rad Studio 10.4.1.

Using a web browser, I downloaded a file of type `psvz`, owned by my app. The iOS Files app shows the file in the browser's download folder and recognizes it as associated with my app. Tapping the filename launches my app. The event handler in my app receives the filename with a path that appears to be in the browser's download folder: `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8CD7612A-2F49-4E20-AD36-4AE092838B0E/Documents/Downloads/HighlandSprings.psvz`.

Attempting to copy the file to a folder in my app with `TFile::Copy` results in a non-existent file error.  `TFile::Exists` says the file doesn't exist.

I'm guessing it's something to do with iOS file permissions or the `/private/` in the filename. How can I process a file passed to a Firemonkey iOS app during launch or how I can un-privatize or otherwise access the file that launched my app?

Comment: Check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867843/ios-how-to-access-private-file-for-sharing-extension

Comment: From further research, it looks like I need startAccessingSecurityScopedResource which Firemonkey doesn't support.